# How to save multiple values on different rows as a variable or list in a CSV using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently trying to iterate through a dataframe/csv and compare the dates of the rows with the same ID. If the dates are different or are a certain time-frame apart I want to create a '1' in another column (not shown) to mark that ID and row/s.

I'm looking to save the DATE values as variables and compare them against other DATE variables with the same ID. If the dates are set amount of time apart I'll create a 1 in another column on the same row.

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11/11/2011 |
| 1 | 11/11/2011 |
| 2 | 5/05/2011 |
| 2 | 20/06/2011 |
| 3 | 2/04/2011 |
| 3 | 10/08/2011 |
| 4 | 8/12/2011 |
| 4 | 1/02/2012 |
| 4 | 12/03/2012 |

For this post, I'm mainly looking to save the multiple values as variables or a list. I'm hoping to figure out the rest once this roadblock has been removed.

Here's what I got currently, but I don't think it'll be much help. Currently it iterates through and converts the date strings to dates. Which is what I want to happen AFTER getting a list of all the dates with the same ID value.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import *
filename = 'TestData.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(filename)

print (df.iloc[0,1])

x = 0

for i in df.iloc:

FixDate = df.iloc[x, 1]

d1, m1, y1 = FixDate.split('/')

d1 = int(d1)
m1 = int(m1)
y1 = int(y1)

finaldate = date(y1, m1, d1)

print(finaldate)

x = x + 1
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: So finnaly need new column filled by `1/0` or something else?

Comment: Yeah I'd need a new column. But I'd imagine I'd add that at the start before going through the dates. Doesn't matter what it's filled with. It's a visual indicator of which rows need to be manually changed.

Comment: `But I'd imagine I'd add that at the start before going through the dates.` Not understand.

Comment: The dataframe doesn't originally contain the 'test' column. To prevent problems my current plan is to add a new column before going through the dates. I believe your solution fixes that issue anyways.

Comment: Ya, it depends what need. First I think need new column `test`, if need sometnigh else new column is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas for performance is best avoid loops, if need new column tested if same values in `DATE` per groups use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)  with [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) and then compare values by `1`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

df['test'] = df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].transform('nunique').eq(1).astype(int)
print (df)
   ID        DATE  test
0   1  11/11/2011     1
1   1  11/11/2011     1
2   2   5/05/2011     0
3   2  20/06/2011     0
4   3   2/04/2011     0
5   3  10/08/2011     0
6   4   8/12/2011     0
7   4   1/02/2012     0
8   4  12/03/2012     0
```

If need filter matched rows:

```
mask = df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].transform('nunique').eq(1)

df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
   ID        DATE
0   1  11/11/2011
1   1  11/11/2011
```

In last step convert values to lists:

```
IDlist  = df1['ID'].tolist()
```

Comment: That's awesome, I'll read through the documentation you've linked so I can understand how to create something similar for the future. I'll see if what you've sent is the solution I need.

I tried to keep post fairly small, but I realize the post may need context. What I actually need to do is create a mark for any DATE that are two months apart and have the same ID. Which is why I thought I could save the date values as variables?

Comment: @Ciecmah - Ya, in pandas the best avoid loops, it is obviously many lines of code, slow and mainly not necessary (if exist pandas function for it)